# Combine csv files of different formats and make into one excel with different sheets

Tags: r, excel, export

I have four csv files with different formats and variables, combining these 4 CSV files into one excel file using below code

```
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)
rm(list = ls())

# getting the path of all reports (they are in csv format)
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

# creating work book
wb <- createWorkbook()

# going through each csv file
for (item in files)
{
    # create a sheet in the workbook
    sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName=strsplit(item,"[.]")[[1]][1])

    # add the data to the new sheet
    addDataFrame(read.csv(item), sheet,row.names=FALSE)
}


# saving the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "crosstabs of data.xlsx")
```

In csv file one sheet the variable name is source / Medium But it is appeared in output excel file as Source...Medium, 
% New Sessions variable is appeared as X..New.Sessions
and all variables delimited space occupied with . in output excel file
How to overcome this i need what ever the variable names in CSV files same as in output Excel file

Comment: Issue comes from `read.csv` that will internally use `make.names` on the header of the file to have names suitable in R for variables. You may try specifying parameter `check.names=FALSE` within the call of `read.csv`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to read.csv changing names of headers. Column headers like `gi/joe` will be converted in `gi.joe` if we do `read.csv` with `header=T`. So one need to convert just the header names again using:

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\.","/",names(df))
```

OR if acceptable do simply (read headers as data):

```
addDataFrame(read.csv(item,header=F), sheet,row.names=FALSE)
```

On a separate note looks like names like `gi/joe` are not allowed as excel sheet names. Now to validate limitation in excel end open excel and try to name a sheet `hi/5`. One should get error saying `The sheet name contains invalid characters: : \ / ? * [ ].` [I am testing this on mac excel 15.19.1]

Comment: Hi sir thanks for your suggession but there is no problem with sheet name i am facing problem with the variable names

Comment: Would you please tell the name of the sheet, you are facing problems with?

Comment: sheet names are data1, data2, data3, data4 these are 4 sheets in 4 csv files but what happened in first file data1 sheet variable names are not as same as the after exporting into excel

Comment: There is a problem using your code all the numeric variables are converted into character format

Comment: which one? By saying `header=F` I meant all is data none is header. so all data according to first line (which is text) will be converted into text. Change to string should not be problem as there is no data type in excel. However if its not the case then use `sheetData<-read.csv(item)` `names(sheetData) <- gsub("\\.","/",names(sheetData))` `addDataFrame(sheetData,sheet,row.names=FALSE)` this will read the data with correct format and only do operation on column headers.